# VirtualBox kernal error in Windows 10 trying to run Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, windows-10-preview

I installed Windows 10 on my computer like an idiot and now VirtualBox doesn't work trying to use Vagrant.

The first thing I do is run "vagrant up" and I get this error...

```
The guest machine entered is an invalid state while waiting for it to boot. Valid states are "starting, running". The macine is the 'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it, it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the GUI often has more helpful error messages blah blah blah.
```

So then in vitrualbox when I try to start the box I get this...

```
VERR_SUPDRV_HARDENING_EVIL_HANDLE(rc=-3738)

Make sure the kernal module has been loaded successfully.
```

After closing that error message I get this...

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Homestead_default_1412246587955_75464.

The virtual machine 'Homestead_default_1412246587955_75464' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Jared\VirtualBox VMs\Homestead_default_1412246587955_75464\Logs\VBoxStartup.log'.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

I've made sure virtualization was enabled in the BIOS.

I also tried manual installing these two .inf files.

```
C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/drivers/USB/filter/VBoxUSBMon.inf
C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/drivers/vboxdrv/VBoxDRV.inf
```

Now when I right click these files it gives me the option to install and after I do it says successful but then when I right click them again it still shows the option to install. I don't know if that's normal but either way it doesn't solve the problem.

So that's where I am. I'm trying to run Vagrant 1.6.5 on VirtualBox 4.3.16 for Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: we can't fix this here. Report this issue to the VB bugtracker/forum

Comment: @magicandre1981 we were just looking around for a workaround. Somebody could have found a way to get it working? Your comment pretty much applies to any software that doesn't work when you use it

Comment: this is a QA site, we can't debug 3rd party tools. Ask this here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=2

Comment: Half the question on this site are trouble shooting 3rd party tools. Relax dude.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same errors. Try to install VirtualBox 4.3.12 (older version). That works just fine for me.